# Bypass default AuthorizeFilter in .NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-2.1

I recently updated my .NET Core app from 2.0 to 2.1.

I have an authorize filter that I add during startup as so:

```
var posBearerPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
    .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme‌​)
    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
    .AddRequirements(new POSBearerRequirement())
    .Build();

services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(new BearerAuthorizeFilter(posBearerPolicy));
});
```

Within BearerAuthorizeFilter's OnAuthorizationAsync method, I have the following logic:

```
public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
{
    if (context.Filters.Count(f => f is AuthorizeFilter) > 1 || context.Filters.Any(f => f is AllowAnonymousFilter))
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    return base.OnAuthorizationAsync(context);
}
```

This works exactly as I want it to in .NET Core 2.0. I have a default authorization policy that applies to all of my controllers. If I want to override that policy, then I just add an [Authorize(NAME)] attribute to my controller. Within that OnAuthorizationAsync, it will detect multiple AuthorizeFilter attributes on the controller and then only apply the policies that I've overridden for that particular controller.

However, since updating to .NET Core 2.1, my posBearerPolicy above is -always- getting applied. I have an API controller with a custom attribute that inherits from AuthorizeAttribute that has its own policy defined and everything set up during startup.

Even when that

```
return Task.CompletedTask;
```

line gets hit, the framework is still applying my posBearerPolicy.

Does anyone know what I'm missing? What caused this to change in .NET Core 2.1? How should I re-write the OnAuthorizationAsync method to tell it to skip/bypass the policy if multiple AuthorizationFilters are present?

Comment: Does setting `AllowCombiningAuthorizeFilters` to false as detailed in [SetCompatibilityVersion for ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-2.1#setcompatibilityversion-for-aspnet-core-mvc) help?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new BearerAuthorizeFilter(posBearerPolicy));

        options.AllowCombiningAuthorizeFilters = true;
    });

and

    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new BearerAuthorizeFilter(posBearerPolicy));

        options.AllowCombiningAuthorizeFilters = false;
    });

and neither worked.

Comment: A dirty way is to make a custom filter and check it in your method.